# Error showing Windows_NT 10.0.22621 with logs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

[NPM not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2aTZ.png)

again and again after trying npm install, this issue comes up, in other file it creates something like npm-debug.log, this is a react project that i was working on. Problem started when reportwebvitals problem occured, i tried and updated npm then degraded it and somehow after doing multiple practices, i ended up with this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with NPM and node.js, I think its when your two versions are not in sync with eachother.

From following these instructions, [NPMError](https://sebhastian.com/npm-err-cbapply-is-not-a-function/#:%7E:text=When%20running%20the%20npm%20install%20command%2C%20you%20may,execute%20the%20graceful-fs%20package%20in%20the%20installation%20process.), I re-downloaded nodejs from here [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org/), removed npm from Appdata/Roaming, then restarted my cmd to load these changes - nodejs now uses the npm it has locally and your system won't default to the different version of npm in Appdata/Roaming, solving your error